# How to use DateTime Object split Interval Object

Tags: java, jodatime

I have an `Interval` object：

```
Interval firstInterval = 
new Interval(new DateTime(2017,06,26,07,55,30),new DateTime(2017,06,26,22,55,30));
```

and:

```
DateTime nightToDay = new DateTime(2017, 06, 26, 8, 0, 0);
DateTime dayToNight = new DateTime(2017, 06, 26, 22, 0, 0);
```

I want to get a `Interval[]`：

```
[
 [2017-06-26 07:55:30 ~ 2017-06-26 08:00:00],
 [2017-06-26 08:00:00 ~ 2017-06-26 22:00:00],
 [2017-06-26 22:00:00 ~ 2017-06-26 22:55:30]
]
```

Of course, these parameters aren't fixed, and it is just an example.

Comment: You should be using JDK 8 and the time package, which is modeled after Joda Time.

Comment: but， company ' s projects to use jdk 7

Comment: Tell your company that JDK 7 has already passed the end of its support life.  It's well past time to upgrade.  You are missing out on lambdas, time package, and lots of other things.  JDK 9 is on the way.

Comment: If stuck with Java 7 for now, Joda-Time probably isn’t the worst option, but there still is a better one: [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the Java 8 date and time API to Java 6 and 7. Futureproof too.

Comment: I believe the `Interval` class is in the [ThreeTen Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Not sure about the details.

Comment: The problem with ThreeTen Extra is that it works only with java.time classes. I seems to have no version for Java <= 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your general case is:

- have a first interval with `start` and `end`
- receives a `nightToDay` and `dayToNight` dates
- output must contain 3 intervals:

  1. `start` to `nightToDay`
  2. `nightToDay` to `dayToNight`
  3. `dayToNight` to `end`

And for each case above, you also need to check if the start of the interval is before the end.

If that's what you need, just do:

```
List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<Interval>();
if (firstInterval.getStart().isBefore(nightToDay)) {
    list.add(new Interval(firstInterval.getStart(), nightToDay));
}
if (nightToDay.isBefore(dayToNight)) {
    list.add(new Interval(nightToDay, dayToNight));
}
if (dayToNight.isBefore(firstInterval.getEnd())) {
    list.add(new Interval(dayToNight, firstInterval.getEnd()));
}
```

The `list` will contain all the `Interval` objects you need.
If you need an array, it's easy to convert the list:

```
Interval[] intervals = new Interval[list.size()];
intervals = list.toArray(intervals);
```

The `intervals` array will have all the intervals created.

Comment: The 'nightToDay ' and 'dayToNight'  may be not between  ‘2017-06-26 07:55:30’  and  '2017-06-26 22:55:30'，so, I don't know that result length